# C# Terminal Game Script giving error CS0103

Tags: c#

so my terminal game script is showing an error that says "The name 'b' does not exist in the current context" but on line 19 b is defined.

```
using System;

namespace Csharp_Game

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string screen1 = ".-";
            string screen2 = ",.";
            string screen3 = ".,";
            string screen4 = ",-";
            string screen5 = "..";
            Console.WriteLine(screen1);
            Console.WriteLine(screen2);
            for (int i = 0; i <= 250; i++)
            {
                string b = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (b=="right1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(screen1);
                Console.WriteLine(screen3);
            }
            if (b=="up1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(screen4);
                Console.WriteLine(screen5);               
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are defining 'b' inside of the for loop, and then trying to access it outside of the for loop its defined in. Either move the if conditions inside of the loop as well (it seems like that's the intent), or define 'b' outside of the loop.

Comment: Closing as a typo, this has little benefit to future users. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace Csharp_Game
{
    class Program
    {
        string b;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string screen1 = ".-";
            string screen2 = ",.";
            string screen3 = ".,";
            string screen4 = ",-";
            string screen5 = "..";
            Console.WriteLine(screen1);
            Console.WriteLine(screen2);
            for (int i = 0; i <= 250; i++)
            {
                b = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (b=="right1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(screen1);
                Console.WriteLine(screen3);
            }
            if (b=="up1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(screen4);
                Console.WriteLine(screen5);               
            }

        }
    }
}
```